# Routing: Component can not be displayed

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I would like to create a page with the URL localhost:4200/**register**.

This is what I have tried:

src/app/**app-routing-modules.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

src/app/register/**register.component.html**

```html
<p>register works!</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have also imported `AppRoutingModule` in app.modules.ts.

If the URL is localhost:4200/register, the page contains the app component but my component "register" can not be displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The router-outlet must not be in the template f the register component. It indicates where the router should insert the register component when the URL is //register. So it must be in your app component template. https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` should be added in the component which is bootstraped (AppComponent by default)

Try like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent }
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
];
```

register.component.html

```
<p>register works!</p>
```

app.componet.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Note: LandingComponent is just a component which you want to show in default like Home page, login page etc

Comment: Why would you display the app component inside the app component when you're at the root?

Comment: @JBNizet Modified toLandingComponet, Just wanted to add a component name on default root

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my AppComponent, other components will be displayed too, no matter if the url contains "/register" or not. I would like to display ONLY the template of register.

Comment: If you give router outlet in the app.comonent, only the current route will be displayed. Example, register component on /register, login component in /login